# AudioSource.Play() outputs only noise from the sound clip

Tags: unity, c#, audio

I'm trying to reproduce a sound clip on the AudioSource of a game object by using the .Play method. What i'm trying to do is a card game of sorts, but with each card being a different section of a song of a genre. I combine different cards with different genres and when i press play, the combination should start playing, but now when the play button is pressed, only noise comes out. The code for the start method looks like this:

```
public class AudioStart : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource thisAudioSource;
    
    
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        thisAudioSource = this.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (playButton.playPressed) {
            thisAudioSource.Play();
        }
        else {
            thisAudioSource.Stop();
        }
    
    }
}
```

The way i'm doing it is by having a button that on click changes a bool to true or false depending if there is sound playing (the truth check on the if statement). The AudioSource outputs to an AudioMixer on a specific group under the master group (which group depends on the slot that the card is dropped in). The AudioStart script is attached to different game objects with a different audio clip each. I've also noticed that when i try to reproduce two cards, only one AudioSource gets played. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: > "using the .Play method": Your code snippet shows `PlayOneShot`.  Without parenthesis, it won't even compile.  Are you using `Play` or `PlayOneShot`?  It's hard to diagnose a bug if you don't share the actual code with the bug.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't notice that. I tried PlayOneShot to see if it worked (read about that in some forum), but i got nothing, and it seems i forgot to rewrite it. Fixed it now. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. You are constantly calling `Play()` inside `Update()`. As far as I remember, `Play()` will start from beginning of audio clip each time it is called. Try this: `if (playButton.playPressed && !thisAudioSource.isPlaying)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PlayOneShot()` will start playing the audio every time the function is called, so calling it in your `Update()` function will cause the clip to start playing every single frame. You get noise because the audio clip is playing playing multiple times simultaneously.

### Solution

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (playButton.playPressed)
        {
            if (!thisAudioSource.isPlaying)
                thisAudioSource.Play();
        }
        else {
            thisAudioSource.Stop();
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Now it works. Thank you!